Can't format entire Dynamic drive (Windows 10)
I have an SSD that I want to format, but there is a left over boot sector with GPT that I can't seem to write over. This disk had an Ubuntu OS installed on it with its own Dual Boot menu that I created. This Dual Boot menu would only be accessible if I changed the boot order in the BIOS since it normally defaulted to Windows 10. (I think this might sound confusing, but essentially I put the Windows regular boot loader first when I got tired of having to choose my OS each time I booted).
In an attempt to format the entire drive, including the boot sector, I tried using DiskPart with these commands (in this order):

diskpart
list disk


As you can see, 'GPT and 'Dynanic' are listed in the flags. Next I used:

sel disk 2
list partition


Next I used:

sel partition 1 then
delete partition override


Virtual Disk Service error: The operation is not supported by the
object.

So I looked this up and it would seem that since the disk has the 'Dynamic' flag, this operation would not work. So in an attempt to format the entire drive again, I tried using DiskPart with these commands (in this order):

list disk then
lselect disk h then
list partition then
select partition h then
delete partition override
The output message was:


DiskPart successfully deleted the volume

, but when I looked at the devices in Computer Management I can still see the boot region I am attempting to format:

How can I remove this boot sector and format the drive into one partition?
Running Windoww 10 Pro

Try clean in diskpart. Absolutely make sure you have the correct drive selected.

First off, you should not (only) be looking to create a single partition but (also) to get rid of the Dynamic Disk. They’re a relic of the past and a liability. Windows will only let you go back to a “Basic disk” after deleting all partitions.
You can remove all partitions on a disk using the diskpart command clean. It will remove all partitions from a disk. It is effective immediately and will not ask for confirmation. Make sure you have the correct disk selected before issuing this command.
Afterwards, you can then do convert basic in diskpart and/or convert mbr/convert gpt as needed.

You could also just ignore the 512 MB partition because it is not even 0.1% of your total space.
I’d still suggest getting rid of the Dynamic Disks stuff when you have the chance.
